# How to provide has_many through association through 3 models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I hope someone has already experienced this.
Please help me, how can i solve this problem:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author
  belongs_to :publisher
  has_one :address, :through => :publisher
end

class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles
  has_many :addresses, :through => :articles, :source => :address
end
```

I try to get "addresses" for "author", and i get this error in console:

```
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationMacroError: Invalid source reflection macro :has_one :through for has_many :addresses, :through => :articles.  Use :source to specify the source reflection.
```

but `author.articles[0].address` works fine.

I hope you give me advice, how can i solve it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

AR does not like sourcing a `has_many` through a `has_one`. But you can easily get all the addresses with this method on `Author`:

```
def addresses
  articles.map {|article| article.address }
end
```

Comment: Thanks, i can also write something like this: articles.map(&:address). But the idea was to write this using relationships. I tried to do this: "has_many :addresses, :through => :publisher" in Article class, it didn't work. I came to conclusion, that AR not allow use has_many :through multiple times. I hope, i am wrong.

Comment: I don't think AR relationships can do it. This one line is not a bad solution though - it's very clear what the intent is, and you can wrap it into a method so it *looks* like an association.

Answer (score 0):

This solution also worked well for different relation types.

e.g. User.registrations.join_table.periods

but you -can't- apply active_record methods on what is mapped.

e.g. user.periods(:order => :date)
e.g. user.periods.model    etc..

thanks